WebSockets error com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException: Failed to connect
I'm trying to make a kotlin app which will communicate with the Solana blockchain. I have followed the official guides but I'm still encountering a problem. Every time I want to trigger this function by clicking a button it executes up until this line val txResult = walletAdapter.transact(sender) { authResult -> It seems to me that the problem could be unrelated to Solana itself but I'm lacking knowledge about WebSockets and I cannot find a fix for this anywhere.
suspend fun onBuyTicket(ticket: Ticket, sender: ActivityResultSender) {

val programId = SolanaPublicKey.from("FtyTxEhxtMcrzwag97cfabBCLzfdi5K6dhc81ybLqNqh")

// Log program ID
Log.d("Juraj", "Program ID: $programId")

// Counter account has a single seed 'counter'
val seeds = listOf("ticket".encodeToByteArray())
Log.d("Juraj", "Seeds: $seeds")

// Calculate the PDA
val result = ProgramDerivedAddress.find(seeds, programId)
val counterAccountPDA = result.getOrNull()
Log.d("Juraj", "Calculated counterAccountPDA: $counterAccountPDA")

// Check if PDA was successfully calculated
if (counterAccountPDA == null) {
    Log.e("Juraj", "Failed to calculate PDA")
    return
}

// Unwrap the result
val rpcClient = SolanaRpcClient("https://api.devnet.solana.com", KtorNetworkDriver())
val solanaUri = Uri.parse("https://jurajapp.com") // Placeholder or generic URL
val iconUri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/icon.png") // Placeholder or generic icon
val identityName = "My dApp" // The name of your dApp

Log.d("Juraj", "Setting up wallet adapter with URI: $solanaUri, icon: $iconUri, name: $identityName")
val walletAdapter = MobileWalletAdapter(connectionIdentity = ConnectionIdentity(
    identityUri = solanaUri,
    iconUri = iconUri,
    identityName = identityName
))

val encodedInstructionData = Borsh.encodeToByteArray(
    AnchorInstructionSerializer("create_ticket"),
    Args_ticket(ticket.id, ticket.name, ticket.departureTime, ticket.arrivalTime, ticket.price)
)

Log.d("Juraj", "Encoded instruction data: ${encodedInstructionData.joinToString(",") { "%02x".format(it) }}")

val ticketInstruction = TransactionInstruction(
    SolanaPublicKey.from("FtyTxEhxtMcrzwag97cfabBCLzfdi5K6dhc81ybLqNqh"),
    listOf(AccountMeta(counterAccountPDA, false, true)),
    encodedInstructionData
)

Log.d("Juraj", "Ticket instruction: $ticketInstruction")

val blockhashResponse = rpcClient.getLatestBlockhash()
Log.d("Juraj", "Blockhash response: ${blockhashResponse.result?.blockhash}")

val buyTicketMessage = Message.Builder()
    .addInstruction(ticketInstruction)
    .setRecentBlockhash(blockhashResponse.result!!.blockhash)
    .build()

Log.d("Juraj", "Buy ticket message built")

val unsignedIncrementTx = Transaction(buyTicketMessage)
Log.d("Juraj", "Unsigned transaction: ${unsignedIncrementTx.serialize().joinToString(",") { "%02x".format(it) }}")

val txResult = walletAdapter.transact(sender) { authResult ->
    Log.d("Juraj", "Transaction request made")
    val account = SolanaPublicKey(authResult.accounts.first().publicKey)
    Log.d("Juraj", "Signing and sending transaction for account: $account")
    signAndSendTransactions(arrayOf(unsignedIncrementTx.serialize()))
}

when (txResult) {
    is TransactionResult.Success -> {
        Log.d("Juraj", "Transaction successful. Signature:")
    }
    is TransactionResult.NoWalletFound -> {
        Log.e("Juraj", "No wallet found")
        println("No MWA compatible wallet app found on device.")
    }
    is TransactionResult.Failure -> {
        Log.e("Juraj", "Transaction failed. Error: ${txResult.e.message}")
        println("Error during signing and sending transactions: ${txResult.e.message}")
    }
}

}
These are the logs happening when the app prompts me to choose between wallet apps on my phone 
This happens when I choose one of the options Phantom or Solflare
